# How to send out an email using Python after retrying three times while scanning the URL?

Tags: python, json, smtp

I am working on a Python script in which I need to scan all URL's one by one and parse the JSON from it. I am having two URL's currently -

```
http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json
```

And each of the above URL's give the JSON response as -

```
{
 "description": "",
 "statistics": {
  "dataCount": 0,
 }
}
```

Now I need to parse the JSON response and extract the `dataCount` from it. Now I wrote a Python script which can scan all my URL's and parse the JSON response and extract the dataCount from it and show it in this format -

Here dataCount will be actual number -

```
hostnameA - dataCount
hostnameB - dataCount
hostnameC - dataCount
hostnameD - dataCount
hostnameE - dataCount
```

Below is my Python script which works fine and it keeps on running every 100 seconds to scan all the URL and parse it and it gives me the output in the format I am looking for -

```
import requests
from time import sleep

def get_data_count(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return 'could not get page'

    try:
        return int(req.json()['stats']['highPriorityQueueDepth'])
    except TypeError:
        return 'field not found'
    except ValueError:
        return 'not an integer'

def main():
    urls = [
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameB', 'http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json')
    ]

    while True:
        print('')
        for name, url in urls:
            res = get_data_count(url)
            print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
        sleep(100.)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Now I would like to send out an email if the `dataCount` is greater than `100` in any one of the URL's. But there is a catch in this - suppose for the first time if `dataCount` is greater than `100`, then I don't want to send out an email, I will try atleast three times and see if the dataCount is still `100` or not. If the `dataCount` has gone down, then I won't send out an email. But suppose for whatever reason, third time also the dataCount is greater than `100`, then only I will send out an email with all the URL's and its count details in the same format as I am showing above.

I am not sure how to implement this in Python. I wrote a below simple python script which can send out an email to me but not sure how to integrate this with my above Python script -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'fromuser@host.com'
receivers = ['touser@host.com']

message = """From: fromuser@host.com
To: touser@host.com
Subject: Send mail from python!!

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('corp.host.com' )
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print "Mail sent"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
   print "You can't spam. Mail sending failed!"
```

Any help will be appreciated on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a count variable to determine how many times res>=100 for any of your hosts has occurred sequentially.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from time import sleep
import smtplib

def get_data_count(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return 'could not get page'

    try:
        return int(req.json()['stats']['highPriorityQueueDepth'])
    except TypeError:
        return 'field not found'
    except ValueError:
        return 'not an integer'

def send_mail(data):
    sender = 'fromuser@host.com'
    receivers = ['touser@host.com']

    message = """From: fromuser@host.com
    To: touser@host.com
    Subject: Send mail from python!!

    """
    body = ''
    for item in data:
        body = body + '{name} - {res}\n'.format(name=item['name'], res=item['res'])

    message = message + body

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('corp.host.com' )
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
       print "Mail sent"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print "You can't spam. Mail sending failed!"

def main():
    urls = [
        ('hostnameA', 'http://hostnameA:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json'),
        ('hostnameB', 'http://hostnameB:1234/Service/statistics?%24format=json')
    ]

    keepData = []
    while True:
        data = []
        sendMail = False
        print('')

        for name, url in urls:
            res = get_data_count(url)
            print('{name} - {res}'.format(name=name, res=res))
            data.append({'name':name, 'res':res})

        keepData.append([item['res'] for item in data])

        if len(keepData) >= 3:
            count = 0
            for nn in range(len(urls)):
                for item in keepData:
                    if item[nn] >= 100:
                        count = count + 1
                    if count > 2:
                        sendMail = True
                        count = 0
        if len(keepData) >= 3: keepData = keepData[1::]
        if sendMail == True: send_mail(data)
        sleep(100.)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In your example basically you are checking if the count is greater than 100, then, you will sleep for 1 second. Instead of that, can we use the same cycle I am using currently..

Comment: .... Like Sleeping for 100 second only, check whether the data count is greater than 100 or not. if it is not, it will sleep for 100 second,and again now suppose if the count is greater than 100, then it will sleep for 100 second, and then retry again, if the count is still greater than 100, then sleep again for 100 second, and retry again, but if the count is now greater than 100 third time, then only I will send out an email?

Comment: At the end of the third time do you want to send data from all three times that you check or just from the latest check?

Comment: I introduced a count variable to keep track of how many times your desired event has occurred, and will send a mail and reset the count if the event has happened three times in a row. You should be able to easily edit that to meet whatever your preferred conditions are.

Comment: Sure. I can modify this from now on. One quick question. I am not able to understand what does this line mean? `if len([item['res'] for item in data if item['res'] >= 1]) >= 1: count = count+1`. Can you explain that if possible?

Comment: That is a list comprehension that creates a list just res>=100 from the latest round of data. If the length of that list is nonzero then that meets your condition. Keep in mind that the method I provided here only checks that any of the hosts has a res>=100, not that a specific host has gone over 100 three times. For that you will always need to store the previous three data and compare them each time to make sure there is not a trend for one of the hostnames. I wasn't exactly sure what your conditions were.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46968/discussion-between-akiweb-and-pseudocubic)

Comment: This is what I got when i tried your suggestion

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "testing.py", line 92, in main
    if sendMail == True: send_mail(data)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sendMail' referenced before assignment`
not sure what is the problem?
Any idea?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to initialize sendMail to False at the beginning of the loop. sendMail = False right after data = []